# Can't get tagged types to compile inside ZLayer

Tags: scala, scala-3, zio

I have two database connections that I want to be able to separate. I found this [post](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/poor-or-rich-mans-refinement-types-in-scala-3-x/4647/17) that describes how to implement Shapeless style tagged types in Scala 3. However, when I try to create a `ZLayer` with a tagged value, I can never satisfy the implicits. Tried every combination I could think of with typed methods and/or passing type parameters - same result all the time.

For the sake of simplicity, I'll just give example code trying to tag `String` instead.

```scala
object TaggedTypes {
  opaque type Tagged[+V, +Tag] = Any
  type @@[+V, +Tag] = V & Tagged[V, Tag]

  def tag[Tag]: [V] => V => V @@ Tag =
    [V] => (v: V) => v
}

import TaggedTypes.*
trait Tag1
trait Tag2

val layer1: ULayer[String @@ Tag1] = ZLayer.succeed(tag[Tag1]("string1"))
val layer2: ULayer[String @@ Tag2] = ZLayer.succeed(tag[Tag2]("string2"))

val program: UIO[Unit] = for {
  string1 <- ZIO.service[String @@ Tag1]
  string2 <- ZIO.service[String @@ Tag2]
  _ <- zio.Console.printLine(s"This should have value 'string1': ${string1}")
  _ <- zio.Console.printLine(s"This should have value 'string2': ${string2}")
} yield ()
```

If `program` would be run, I would expect values to match as in console log statements.

Instead, compilation fails with:

```
could not find implicit value for izumi.reflect.Tag[(String & TaggedTypes.Tagged[String, Tag1])].
Did you forget to put on a Tag, TagK or TagKK context bound on one of the parameters in (String & TaggedTypes.Tagged[String, Tag1])? e.g. def x[T: Tag, F[_]: TagK] = .... 
I found:  zio.Tag.materialize[ (String & TaggedTypes.Tagged[String, Tag1]) ]  
But method materialize in trait TagVersionSpecific does not match type zio.Tag[(String & TaggedTypes.Tagged[String, Tag1]) ].
```

`zio` is on version `2.0.13`, `izumi-reflect` is on version `2.3.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are trying to do here isn't really the way that ZIO wants you to handle this.
Its mostly possible except you need to have a type tag for each connection (String in the example) that is unique, which I'm not sure how to do.

The code below will always print `string2` because `TaggedString[T]` always returns the same Tag and thus the write to the environment Map is overwritten.

```
import izumi.reflect.dottyreflection.ReflectionUtil.reflectiveUncheckedNonOverloadedSelectable
import zio.{Tag, UIO, ULayer, ZEnvironment, ZIO, ZIOAppDefault, ZLayer}

import java.io.IOException

opaque type Tagged[+V, +Tag] = Any
type @@[+V, +Tag] = V & Tagged[V, Tag]

def tag[Tag]: [V] => V => V @@ Tag = [V] => (v: V) => v

trait Tag1
trait Tag2

object TagExample extends ZIOAppDefault {
  override def run: ZIO[Any, IOException, Unit] = {
    // The problem is to express one of these that is unique for each Tag
    given TaggedString[T]: Tag[String @@ T] = Tag[String].asInstanceOf[Tag[String @@ T]]

    val a: String @@ Tag1 = tag[Tag1]("string1")
    val b: String @@ Tag2 = tag[Tag2]("string2")

    val layer1: ULayer[String @@ Tag1] = ZLayer.succeed[String @@ Tag1](a)
    val layer2: ULayer[String @@ Tag2] = ZLayer.succeed[String @@ Tag2](b)

    val program: ZIO[String @@ Tag1 & String @@ Tag2, IOException, Unit] = for {
       string1 <- ZIO.service[String @@ Tag1]
       string2 <- ZIO.service[String @@ Tag2]
       _ <- zio.Console.printLine(s"This should have value 'string1': ${string1}")
       _ <- zio.Console.printLine(s"This should have value 'string2': ${string2}")
    } yield ()

    program.provideLayer(layer1 ++ layer2)
  }
}
```

However, its MUCH simpler to just wrap the connections in a case class to give them separate types.

This example works properly:

```
import zio.{UIO, ULayer, ZEnvironment, ZIO, ZIOAppDefault, ZLayer}

import java.io.IOException

case class String1(value: String)
case class String2(value: String)

object TagExample extends ZIOAppDefault {
  override def run: ZIO[Any, IOException, Unit] = {
    val layer1: ULayer[String1] = ZLayer.succeed(String1("string1"))
    val layer2: ULayer[String2] = ZLayer.succeed(String2("string2"))

    val program: ZIO[String1 & String2, IOException, Unit] = for {
      string1 <- ZIO.service[String1]
      string2 <- ZIO.service[String2]
      _ <- zio.Console.printLine(s"This should have value 'string1': ${string1.value}")
      _ <- zio.Console.printLine(s"This should have value 'string2': ${string2.value}")
    } yield ()

    program.provideLayer(layer1 ++ layer2)
  }
}
```

Comment: By any chance you happen to know how come it used to work in Scala 2.13 with Shapeless? Though, I think I also used ZIO v1 back then, too